# How can i slightly modify this Swear filter PHP function?

Tags: php, filter

I have this swear filter taking as input from a .txt file having bad words divided by the "|" character. It works great, but it replaces the whole "bad word". How can i slightly modify this so it can leave the first letter of the word in the new string or even better to leave the first and the last ?

```
function filterwords($text){
$bad_words = file(base_url() . '/bad_words.txt');
$filterWords = explode(" | ", $bad_words[0]);
$filterCount = sizeof($filterWords);
for($i=0; $i<$filterCount; $i++){
$text = preg_replace('/\b'.$filterWords[$i].'\b/ie',"str_repeat('*',strlen('$0'))",$text);
}
return $text;
}
```

Comment: `substr('$0',0 , 1) . str_repeat('*',strlen('$0')-2) . substr('$0', -1)`

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

Comment: Where exactly do i put this line of code you provided ?

Comment: You use it to replace the `str_repeat('*',strlen('$0'))` that you already had